# Nested Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

Is there any possibility to make this below UI ?
Activity->Fragment->Multi Fragment.

i.e : A fragment inside of an Activity which have multi fragment.

If it is then please give me an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible and I have completed it. In Activity's layout I have used two fragments. It is static initialization of fragment. Then in every fragment I have used another fragment. But for communication I have used listener which have been implemented by the main Activity. It is solved here :
https://github.com/sajidkhan2067/ComplexDesign